# Searching for a string with variables, then extracting that variable

Tags: vb.net, parsing, search, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Hello fellow programmers,

So I've been trying to parse a webpage from an `HttpWebResponse` and was wondering if there exists a function to take my response string and search for a string that will have dynamic variables inside of it in order to extract those variables.

For example, let's say the the web response string reads

```
Line 1 <input type="hidden" name="ahfsjjdfh" value="ajdghd">
Line 2 <input type="hidden" name="sfadgs" value="fgdgd">
Line 3 <input type="hidden" name="fgfdasd" value="gfdefaq">
Line 4 <input type="hidden" value="gfdefaq">
```

I would want to search for the string input type="hidden" name=*VARIABLE1 value=*VARIABLE2 and if found get both VARIABLE1 and VARIABLE2, but not just VARIABLE1 as in line 4. Stated in another way, I would want the names and values for lines 1-3, but not the value for line 4.

Is there a way to do this with a search function?

Comment: What's the page's `<!doctype>`? If it is XHTML, you can treat it as XML. In other words: you'd be able to use something like XPath or LINQ to XML, without having to write a terrible amount of extra code just to get what you want.

Comment: No it is not an xhtml. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using `regex.matches(string, regex)`.